# Online coding collaboration tool

Tags: repository

I was wondering if you guys have experience with any online tool that allows coding collaboration with notifications that gets fired each time a contributor edits/adds to the source file.

I was exploring github but I am not sure if notification is supported (or atleast I couldnt get that to work) when a contributor commits a new change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github does support notification  and of course Github is the most mature collaboration env in the cloud.

[Notification Enh](https://github.com/blog/584-notification-improvements)

Comment: I was also wondering. Android Developers silently released a python library to work with Git. It was supposed to have automated most of the day to day coding collaboration. Its called Repo. I wanted to try it, but did not find time. If its a new project, then you should take a look.